# Is it possible to erase a capture group that has already matched, making it non-participating?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

In PCRE2 or any other regex engine supporting forward backreferences, is it possible to change a capture group that matched in a previous iteration of a loop into a *non-participating capture group* (also known as an *unset capture group* or *non-captured group*), causing conditionals that test that group to match with their "false" clause rather than their "true" clause?

For example, take the following PCRE regex:

```
^(?:(z)?(?(1)aa|a)){2}
```

When fed the string `zaazaa`, it matches the whole string, as desired. But when fed `zaaaa`, I would like it to match `zaaa`; instead, it matches `zaaaa`, the whole string. (This is just for illustration. Of course this example could be handled by `^(?:zaa|a){2}` but that is beside the point. Practical usage of capture group erasure would tend to be in loops that most often do far more than 2 iterations.)

An alternative way of doing this, which also doesn't work as desired:

```
^(?:(?:z()|())(?:\1aa|\2a)){2}
```

Note that both of these work as desired when the loop is "unrolled", because they no longer have to erase a capture that has already been made:

```
^(?:(z)?(?(1)aa|a))(?:(z)?(?(2)aa|a))
^(?:(?:z()|())(?:\1aa|\2a))(?:(?:z()|())(?:\3aa|\4a))
```

So instead of being able to use the simplest form of conditional, a more complicated one must be used, which only works in this example because the "true" match of `z` is non-empty:

```
^(?:(z?)(?(?!.*$\1)aa|a)){2}
```

Or just using an emulated conditional:

```
^(?:(z?)(?:(?!.*$\1)aa|(?=.*$\1)a)){2}
```

I have scoured all the documentation I can find, and there seems not to even be any mention or explicit description of this behavior (that captures made within a loop persist through iterations of that loop even when they fail to be re-captured).

It's different than what I intuitively expected. The way I would implement it is that evaluating a capture group with 0 repetitions would erase/unset it (so this could happen to any capture group with a `*`, `?`, or `{0,N}` quantifier), but skipping it due to being in a parallel alternative within the same group in which it gained a capture during a previous iteration would not erase it. Thus, this regex would still match words iff they [contain at least one of every vowel](https://twitter.com/DrRegex/status/925591453627305990):

```
\b(?:a()|e()|i()|o()|u()|\w)++\1\2\3\4\5\b
```

But skipping a capture group due to it being inside an unevaluated alternative of a group that is evaluated with nonzero repetitions which is nested within the group in which the capture group took on a value during a previous iteration *would* erase/unset it, so this regex would be able to either capture or erase group `\1` on every iteration of the loop:

```
^(?:(?=a|(b)).(?(1)_))*$
```

and would match strings such as `aaab_ab_b_aaaab_ab_aab_b_b_aaa`. However, the way forward references are actually implemented in existing engines, it matches `aaaaab_a_b_a_a_b_b_a_b_b_b_`.

I would like to know the answer to this question not merely because it would be useful in constructing regexes, but because I have [written my own regex engine](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine), currently ECMAScript-compatible with some optional extensions (including molecular lookahead `(?*)`, i.e. non-atomic lookahead, which as far as I know, no other engine has), and I would like to continue adding features from other engines, including forward/nested backreferences. Not only do I want my implementation of forward backreferences to be compatible with existing implementations, but if there *isn't* a way of erasing capture groups in other engines, I will probably create a way of doing it in my engine that doesn't conflict with other existing regex features.

To be clear: An answer stating that this is not possible in any mainstream engines will be acceptable, as long as it is backed up by adequate research and/or citing of sources. An answer stating that it *is* possible would be much easier to state, since it would require only one example.

Some information on what a non-participating capture group is:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/npcg-javascript - this is the article that originally introduced me to the idea.
https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html - the first section on this page gives a brief explanation.
In ECMAScript/Javascript regexes, backreferences to NPCGs always match (making a zero-length match). In pretty much every other regex flavor, they fail to match anything.

Comment: I believe `\K` will tell the regex engine to clear all capture groups, but I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: The only  mistake you were doing in the first Regex of the question was you were asking it to capture first group 2 times, which was aa. So I removed it, Let whole group capture and then let it repeat if you want or at least one time.

Comment: @Deep Thanks but you did misunderstand my question. The example I gave was just a toy example. I want to be able to erase capture groups while staying inside a loop and continuing to loop. I only gave it `{2}` repetitions to make it a very simple example; in practice, I'd mostly be using this on unbounded loops like `(...)+` and `(...)*` where `...` means whatever would go inside the loop.

Comment: Can you put example string somewhere where we can play with the data. It would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: @Deep I'll try, but it's not any particular example task that matters in this case, it's the *way* it's done. There is no task that *requires* this, it's just that being able to erase a capture could make certain tasks doable in a more elegant way.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen `\K` just changes where the final match begins, and does not affect the contents of capture groups at all. I don't actually care about the final match in this example; it's only an example to differentiate and demonstrate/explain what I want to do inside the loop. I want to erase the capture group during a loop, while staying in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is partially possible in .NET's flavour of regex.

The first thing to note is that .NET records all of the captures for a given capture group, not just the latest. For instance, `^(?=(.)*)` records each character in the first line as a separate capture in the group.

To actually delete captures, .NET regex has a construction known as [balancing groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition). The full format of this construction is `(?<name1-name2>subexpression)`.

- First, `name2` must have previously been captured.
- The subexpression must then match.
- If `name1` is present, the substring between the end of the capture of `name2` and the start of the subexpression match is captured into `name1`.
- The latest capture of `name2` is then deleted. (This means that the old value could be backreferenced in the subexpression.)
- The match is advanced to the end of the subexpression.

If you know you have `name2` captured exactly once then it can readily be deleted using `(?<-name2>)`; if you don't know whether you have `name2` captured then you could use `(?>(?<-name2>)?)` or a conditional. The problem arises if you might have `name2` captured more than once since then it depends on whether you can organise enough repetitions of the deletion of `name2`. (`(?<-name2>)*` doesn't work because `*` is equivalent to `?` for zero-length matches.)

Answer (score 5):

I found this documented in PCRE's man page, under "DIFFERENCES BETWEEN PCRE2 AND PERL":

> ```
>    12.  There are some differences that are concerned with the settings of
>    captured strings when part of  a  pattern  is  repeated.  For  example,
>    matching  "aba"  against  the  pattern  /^(a(b)?)+$/  in Perl leaves $2
>    unset, but in PCRE2 it is set to "b".
> ```

I'm struggling to think of a practical problem that cannot be better solved with an alternative solution, but in the interests of keeping it simple, here goes:

Suppose you have a simple task well-suited to being solved by using forward references; for example, check the input string is a palindrome. This cannot be solved generally with recursion (due to the atomic nature of subroutine calls), and so we bang out the following:

```
/^(?:(.)(?=.*(\1(?(2)\2))))*+.?\2$/
```

Easy enough. Now suppose we are asked to verify that *every line in the input* is a palindrome. Let's try to solve this by placing the expression in a repeated group:

```
\A(?:^(?:(.)(?=.*(\1(?(2)\2))))*+.?\2$(?:\n|\z))+\z
```

Clearly that doesn't work, since the value of \2 persists from the first line to the next. This is similar to the problem you're facing, and so here are a number of ways to overcome it:

**1. Enclose the entire subexpression in `(?!(?! ))`:**

```
\A(?:(?!(?!^(?:(.)(?=.*(\1(?(2)\2))))*+.?\2$)).+(?:\n|\z))+\z
```

Very easy, just shove 'em in there and you're essentially good to go. Not a great solution if you want any particular captured values to persist.

**2. Branch reset group to reset the value of capture groups:**

```
\A(?|^(?:(.)(?=.*(\1(?(2)\2))))*+.?\2$|\n()()|\z)+\z
```

With this technique, you can reset the value of capture groups from the first (\1 in this case) up to a certain one (\2 here). If you need to keep \1's value but wipe \2, this technique will not work.

**3. Introduce a group that captures the remainder of the string from a certain position to help you later identify where you are:**

```
\A(?:^(?:(.)(?=.*(\1(?(2)(?=\2\3\z)\2))([\s\S]*)))*+.?\2$(?:\n|\z))+\z
```

The whole rest of the collection of lines is saved in \3, allowing you to reliably check whether you have progressed to the next line (when `(?=\2\3\z)` is no longer true).

This is one of my favourite techniques because it can be used to solve tasks that seem impossible, such as the ol' [matching nested brackets using forward references](http://www.drregex.com/2017/11/match-nested-brackets-with-regex-new.html). With it, you can maintain any other capture information you need. The only downside is that it's horribly inefficient, especially for long subjects.

**4. This doesn't really answer the question, but it solves the problem:**

```
\A(?![\s\S]*^(?!(?:(.)(?=.*(\1(?(2)\2))))*+.?\2$))
```

This is the alternative solution I was talking about. Basically, "re-write the pattern" :) Sometimes it's possible, sometimes it isn't.

Comment: As a side note, the difference part is not specific to PCRE2.

Comment: +1, Very nice answer (not technically an answer but still useful), with a great example of a problem that would benefit from capture group erasing, and at least one method of working around the issue I hadn't thought of.
And interesting thing to know about Perl; `/^(?:(z)?(?(1)aa|a)){2}/` actually works the way I want in it (differently from PCRE). However, the alternative version, `/^(?:(?:(z)|)(?(1)aa|a)){2}/`, works the same in Perl and PCRE (which is not the way I want).

Comment: Note that the enclosing-in-`(?!`...`)` trick often doesn't work in Perl. It lets capture groups' contents leak out of a negative lookahead in some circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

With PCRE (and all as I'm aware) it's not possible to unset a capturing group but using subroutine calls since their nature doesn't remember values from the previous recursion, you are able to accomplish the same task:

```
(?(DEFINE)((z)?(?(2)aa|a)))^(?1){2}
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/O4kQWB/1)

If you are going to implement a behavior into your own regex flavor to unset a capturing group, I'd strongly suggest do not let it happen automatically. Just provide some flags.

Comment: This is indeed a viable method in some cases, but the downside is that you also can't return any captures from a subroutine call in PCRE. The choice is either between capturing the entirety of what the subroutine matches, or not capturing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to "erase" capture groups in .NET. Unlike the `(?<-name>)` method, this empties the group instead of deleting it – so instead of not matching, it will then match an empty string.

In .NET, groups with the same name can be captured multiple times, even if that name is a number. This allows PCRE expressions using balanced groups to be ported to .NET. Consider this PCRE pattern:

```
(?|(pattern)|())
```

Assuming both groups are `\1` above, then using this technique, in .NET it would become:

```
(?:(pattern)|(?<1>))
```

I used this technique today to make a 38 byte .NET regex that [matches strings whose length is a fourth power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223129/17216):

```
^((?=(?>^((?<3>\3|x))|\3(\3\2))*$)){2}
```

the above is a port of the following 35 byte PCRE regex, which uses balanced groups:

```
^((?=(?|^((\2|x))|\2(\2\3))*+$)){2}
```

(In this example, the capture group isn't actually being emptied. But this technique can be used to do anything a balanced group can do, including emptying a group.)